# Why does non-trivial destructor of return type prevent tail-call optimization?

Tags: c++, c++17, tail-call-optimization, return-value-optimization

Currently, in C++ compilers one of the rules for tail-call optimization is that the return type must be trivially destructible. (Based on analyzing GCC, Clang trunk behavior. MSVC has troubles with any non-trivial types).

Is this requirement still necessary? With C++17 return-value-optimization being mandatory, it seems like the function could still use trail-call optimization, even when the return type is non-trivial. What is the problem here, that prevents compilers from that?

@edit, code example:

```
#include <string>

bool h();

std::string g() {
    std::string s1 = "a", s2 = "b";
    if (h()) return s1;
    else return s2;
}

std::string f() {
    return g();  // <= here I'd expect call-tail optimization due to RVO, since it is prvalue
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YYfMr6xdd

If I understand the assembly correctly, it should be possible to replace f() function with jump.

Comment: If *I* understand correctly `f` can be replaced by `g` (inlining) (non mandatory I guess). And `g` doesn't have NRVO (or RVO) because it has multiple return paths.

Comment: Both gcc and clang save and restore $rdi -> $rax. Maybe they don't assume that `g` sets up $rax properly?

Comment: This isn't directly related to trivially-destructible, but to whether or not the ABI allows passing through registers. If the type is trivially destructible but big enough, the tail call is also not optimized: https://godbolt.org/z/TbrM74j7b

Comment: @dyp, yes, this is the first time I hear trivial-destruction in connection to (N)RVO. I think not being trivial is not an excuse to prevent (N)RVO. The implicit idea is that elided destruction don't have side effects or are not important if the construction was elided in the first place.

Comment: I'm almost sure, that passing these values in registers is dependent on trivial destructibility of the type. Clang [[clang::musttail]] attribute returns an error, that the type must be trivially destructible, and same wording is used in many trivially-relocable / bitcopy-movable proposals. After some research I heard the same thing in Herb Sutter/Niall Douglas talks, and if I understood them correctly, this small-value ABI inefficiency is caused by non-trivial destructors.

Answer (score 0):

Return value optimization is *only* mandatory if you are returning a temporary (more precisely: a `prvalue` - see also [here on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)), e.g. in this case:

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
  return std::vector<int>{1,2};
}
```

If you are returning a local object, this is *Named* Return Value Optimization (a.k.a. "Copy Elision"), which is not mandatory (but still done most of the time), e.g. in this case:

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
  std::vector<int> myVec{1,2};
  return myVec;
}
```

The compiler is in this case allowed to first construct `myVec` inside `foo()`s frame, return by copy, and destroy. Obviously most compilers won't do this. Still, a destruction *can* happen when `foo()` ends.

I guess that this is the reason for requiring trivial destructors for tail-call optimization. If `foo()` is tail-call optimized, the standard must account for the create/return-by-copy/destory lifecycle, and thus have a way of (trivially) destroying the returned object.